How can I get the latitude and longitude of a grid?
I'm currently working on a project where I need to identify all the intersecting points within a grid on the USA map. My objective is to divide the map into 1km square sections and obtain the latitude and longitude coordinates of the four corners of each square.
Let's say we have the map of the continental USA and it has the grid (Let's say, like graticules) on top of it. The side of each line of the grid is 1km.

If we zoom in, that grid will look like this, points representing the intersecting points of the grid. I need the latitude and longitude of those points.

My current approach involves using QGIS to generate a 0.01-degree grid covering the entire continental US territory. Initially, I followed a tutorial on creating a polygonal grid for the entire world. After that, I adapted the steps to focus solely on the US by importing the USA Shapefile from Census.gov. However, I've encountered an issue when attempting to extract the coordinates of the grid intersections. Unfortunately, the method I've been using to get lat, lng from the points isn't returning valid latitude and longitude pairs.
I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions or alternative methods for accurately mapping the entire continental US using such grid points. Thank you!

I do not understand fully your problem. If you put your code and if you state exactly what problem did you encounter, we may help better. UTM is often used, but if you want to create your scale, just define a central point (both with lat, long, and what you want as x,y), then just calculate easting and northing (length of a degree of latitude and longitude). [Then verify the size of error: e.g. take extreme points and check real latitudes and calculate distances with your methods and with geographic libraries (on x,y system ,which it is the system with "projection"].

Thank you, @GiacomoCatenazzi, I've added some graphics and some more details.

Found a way to do this by grabbing an ESRI Shapefile of urban areas from the US Census website. This is the script I ended up with, just feed it a Geo ID and will do the mapping. You can find the list of Geo IDs on my Gist.
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import mapping, shape
from fiona.transform import transform_geom
from shapely import speedups
from shapely.geometry import Point
import math
import sys, os

def get_bbox_fixed(bounds):
    # Fixing bbox to start on 100 m coordinate
    minx = math.floor(bounds[0] / 100) * 100
    miny = math.floor(bounds[1] / 100) * 100
    maxx = math.ceil(bounds[2] / 100) * 100
    maxy = math.ceil(bounds[3] / 100) * 100
    # print([minx, miny, maxx, maxy])
    return [minx, miny, maxx, maxy]

def create_grid(bbox, poly, id):
    epsg3746 = "epsg:3746"  # Metric system covering US
    epsg4326 = "epsg:4326"  # Geography WGS 84 system
    points_in_grid = round(((bbox[2] + 30 - bbox[0]) / 30) * ((bbox[3] + 30 - bbox[1]) / 30))
    rows_in_grid = round((bbox[2] + 30 - bbox[0]) / 30)
    print("Number of points in BBOX: " + str(points_in_grid))
    print("Number of rows in BBOX: " + str(rows_in_grid))
    with open('output/' + id + '.csv', 'w') as out:
        row = 0
        for x in range(bbox[0], bbox[2] + 30, 30):
            for y in range(bbox[1], bbox[3] + 30, 30):
                # Creating point on row, column coordinate
                p = Point([x, y])
                # Checking if the point is inside the polygon of the urban area
                if p.within(poly):
                    # Transforming point into WGS 84
                    p_transformed = transform_geom(epsg3746, epsg4326, mapping(p))
                    p_transformed_shape = shape(p_transformed)
                    out.write(str(p_transformed_shape.x) + ',' + str(p_transformed_shape.y) + '\n')
            row += 1
            if row % 10 == 0:
                print("Processed " + str(row) + " rows from " + str(rows_in_grid) + " rows.")

speedups.enable()

epsg3746 = "epsg:3746"
epsg4269 = "epsg:4269"

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("You have to specify GEOID20 of the area")
    exit()

if os.path.exists("tl_2023_us_uac20.shp"):
    with fiona.open("tl_2023_us_uac20.shp", "r") as uacs:
        # Loop via polygons of urban areas
        for uac in uacs:
            if uac['properties']['GEOID20'] == sys.argv[1]:
                print("Processing " + sys.argv[1])
                # Transforms polygon into metric system
                geom_transformed = transform_geom(epsg4269, epsg3746, uac["geometry"])
                poly = shape(geom_transformed)
                fixed_bounds = get_bbox_fixed(poly.bounds)
                create_grid(fixed_bounds, poly, uac['properties']['GEOID20'])
                break
else:
    print("You have to place us_uac_20 ESRI Shapefile in the same directory where is the script located. You can download the data from: https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2023/UAC/")


